# listing contents of an R data file without loading

Tags: r

I sometimes use `print( load( "myDataFile.RData" ) )` to list the contents of a data file when I load it. Is there a way to list the contents without loading the objects contained in the data file?

Answer (score 6):

I do not think you could do that without loading the object.

A solution could be to save the R objects with a wrapper to `save`, which function would save the object AND the structure of the object to a special Rdata file. Later you could load the special binary file with a wrapper to `load`, where you could specify to only list the structure of the data.

I have done something like this in a very basic package, named [saves](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/saves/index.html), can be found on CRAN.

---

**Update:** I made up a *very* simple metadata solution

```
save.ls <- function(x, file) {
    save(list=x, file=file)
    l <- ls()
    save(l, file=paste(file, 'ls', sep=''))
}
load.ls <- function(file) {
    attach(paste(file, 'ls', sep=''));
    return(l)
    detach(pos=2)
}
```

Save with `save.ls` instead of `save` and load with `load.ls` to test. Meta information is saved in separate file (ending in "ls"), but the mechanism could be improved easily e.g. making a tar archive (like I do in the package linked above) of the Rdata object and the file containing the metadata.

Comment: A metadata solution does make sense. I don't know beans about R data files and thought they might have internal metadata

Comment: @JD Long: that is the only way I could imagine. I made up a primitive example in my answer above to show what I meant. It could be implemented easily in a much neater way though, so this demo function is definitely not ready for production use :)

Comment: The metadata solution in R exists already and is called called lazy-loading - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700619/get-specific-object-from-rdata-file

Answer (score 5):

```
attach(file);ls(pos=2);detach(pos=2)
```

That'll do it. Probably. #untested

Comment: You can omit `pos=2` in `detach`, since `detach()` detaches 2nd item in search path by default.

Comment: I tested that suggestion by Ripley that I found in the archive  and did not submit it, since it _did_ load a rather large dataset I used as my example.

Comment: attach and load are the only well-defined ways to access .RData files from the R level (you could open them as a binary connection and read if you knew the file format). If someone wants to write C code that goes beyond that (or R code on a binary connection), I'm sure it might be welcome into the core...

Comment: Yes, `attach()` *does* call `load()` is it makes no difference, you could as well simply use `local(load(file))` with the same result.

Answer (score 4):

In R v3.0.1 the `load()` function got a new argument. Loading an RData file with

```
load("mydata.RData", verbose=TRUE)
```

will show you the objects that are loaded. Of course, it still means you have to load the object.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,

```
load( "myDataFile.RData",ex<-new.env() )
content=ls.str(ex)
```