# Get specific object from Rdata file

Tags: r, object, rdata

I have a `Rdata` file containing various objects:

```
 New.Rdata
  |_ Object 1  (e.g. data.frame)
  |_ Object 2  (e.g. matrix)
  |_...
  |_ Object n
```

Of course I can load the data frame with `load('New.Rdata')`, however, is there a smart way to load only one specific object out of this file and discard the others?

Comment: In comments, @DWin says no. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550510/examining-contents-of-rdata-file-by-attaching-into-a-new-environment-possible

Comment: But in all matters-R I defer to Simon.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

.RData files don't have an index (the contents are serialized as one big pairlist). You could hack a way to go through the pairlist and assign only entries you like, but it's not easy since you can't do it at the R level.

However, you can simply convert the .RData file into a lazy-load database which serializes each entry separately and creates an index. The nice thing is that the loading will be on-demand:

```
# convert .RData -> .rdb/.rdx
e = local({load("New.RData"); environment()})
tools:::makeLazyLoadDB(e, "New")
```

Loading the DB then only loads the index but not the contents. The contents are loaded as they are used:

```
lazyLoad("New")
ls()
x # if you had x in the New.RData it will be fetched now from New.rdb
```

Just like with `load()` you can specify an environment to load into so you don't need to pollute the global workspace etc.

Comment: But the look-up will still require a serial access through "New.RData" to get "x", right? So if "x" is at the end of "New.RData", there might be no time savings? Question2: won't there be memory taken up with the other objects encountered as the unserialization process works its way through "New.RData"?

Comment: No, the lookup just seeks into `New.rdb` at the beginning of `x` and loads only `x`.

Comment: What are the chances of these functions becoming less internal?

Comment: This does not work if the data files are larger.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `attach` rather than `load` which will attach the data object to the search path, then you can copy the one object you are interested in and detach the .Rdata object.

This still loads everything, but is simpler to work with than loading everything into the global workspace (possibly overwriting things you don't want overwritten) then getting rid of everything you don't want.

Comment: This answer is good but would be more complete with an example, because detaching the .RData object from the search path is not intuitive.  Example to retrieve `someObj` from `someFile.RData`:  `attach('someFile.RData'); someObj <- someObj; detach('file:someFile.RData')`

Comment: @C8H10N4O2, your example is good (and very explicit).  But if you attach in the default position (2) and don't attach anything else before calling detach, then the defaults work and you can just call `detach()` without any arguments and it will detach the file.  This is quicker and simpler; your approach is safer.

Answer (score 7):

Simon Urbanek's answer is very, very nice.  A drawback is that it doesn't seem to work if an object to be saved is too large:

```
tools:::makeLazyLoadDB(
  local({
    x <- 1:1e+09
   cat("size:", object.size(x) ,"\n")
   environment()
  }), "lazytest")
size: 4e+09 
Error: serialization is too large to store in a raw vector
```

I'm guessing that this is due to a limitation of the current implementation of R (I have 2.15.2) rather than running out of physical memory and swap. The [saves](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/saves/index.html) package might be an alternative for some uses, however.

Comment: This is more of an extended comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 5):

A function is useful to extract a single object without loading everything in the RData file.

```
extractorRData <- function(file, object) {
      #' Function for extracting an object from a .RData file created by R's save() command
      #' Inputs: RData file, object name
      E <- new.env()
      load(file=file, envir=E)
      return(get(object, envir=E, inherits=F))
    }
```

See full answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65964065/4882696

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2012/04/01/saving-and-loading-r-objects/) gives an a neat practice that prevents this sort of issue in the first problem. The gist of it is to use `saveRDS(), loadRDS()` functions instead of the regular `save(), load()` functions.