# List of variables from R workspace file

Tags: r, workspace

I am wondering if there is any way to get the list of variables in R workspace file (.RData) before loading it? 
I mean any function which could look like: `ls('/Users/xxx/workspace.RData');`
Thanks a lot for your help!
Tomek

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  I think I have an idea of why you want to do it and there is a better way to do what you want that doesn't require it but it would be nice to verify that my suspicion is correct.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8703024/489704).

Comment: I've my own software that communicates with R via Rserve package. When loading a saved workspace I'd like to check which variables are new. Of course, I can check `ls()` before loading workspace and after it and compare them using `setdiff`, but if I had a varible e.g. x = 5, and after loading workspace with x = 7, the the described method won't detect the change.