# Only source functions in a .R file

Tags: r

I would like  `source()` to only find and load functions within a `.R` file.

For example, in the file Analysis.R:

```
print.hw <- function() {
    print("hello world")
}

x <- 1 + 2
...
```

When I `source("Analysis.R")`, it will create the function `print.hw` but also assign `x`, which I do not want.

Anyone have any ideas? The best I could find was this question:

[Source only part of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214963/source-only-part-of-a-file)

Comment: `source()` is designed to execute all the commands in a file. Both of those commands in your example are assigning a result to a variable. They aren't really that different. What about `x<-function(a) function(x) x+1; b<-x(5); b(4)`. Both of those "create functions." Would you want to run them both?

Comment: @RichardScriven, the linked answer would help if I were able to find the lines containing `function(...){`, and pair it with the closing `}`.

Comment: @MrFlick, I only want to assign variables where these variables are functions. I could rephrase my question to say that I only want to execute all commands that are related to defining functions.

Comment: @Alex R is not strongly typed. A variable can be anything and may change at any time. You need to run and execute the code to see what it is at any given moment.

Comment: @RichardScriven, yes definitely, as I can then supply the required arguments to `source2` in the linked answer.

Comment: @MrFlick I don't understand what you mean by the last comment. Are you saying that R does not understand what things will assign variables of type function until the code is run?

Comment: @Alex. Correct. For example: `f<-if(runif(1)<.5) {function(x) x+1} else {4}` Is `f` a function or a numeric value?

Comment: @MrFlick I see what you mean now, but luckily I do not wish to run that example you supplied. (My code has no examples like that).

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven, that at first glance seems to give the right line number pairs.

Comment: Perhaps the question earlier today the led to a link to a description of lazy loading could be of use? Load the index into an environment and process from there?

Comment: @BondedDust which question is this?

Comment: what happened to @RichardScriven's answers and comments?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616958/list-of-variables-from-r-workspace-file

Comment: @RichardScriven, why did you delete your answer ... ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works without using regex. It's also probably less computationally efficient than regex solutions. It creates a new environment, sources the entire file, then returns only the functions back to the global environment.

```
SourceFunctions<-function(file) {
  MyEnv<-new.env()
  source(file=file,local=MyEnv)
  list2env(Filter(f=is.function,x=as.list(MyEnv)),
           envir=parent.env(environment()))
}
```

Comment: see also: `sys.source`

Comment: Here's some alternate syntax: `list2env(Filter(is.function, as.list(MyEnv)),globalenv())`

Answer (score 0):

I think its a good practice to separate test code before the end of source files (as we usually do in Python) and then invoke them with external scripts or packages (like [testthat](https://cran.r-project.org/package=testthat)). Hadley's [dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) may give you a reference.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question; it just says "don't do it that way".  More of a comment.