# Print or write RData file to view file contents

Tags: r, rdata

I have a `.RData` file that has multiple objects of varying type and size. I can't view by printing, because I can only see half the objects (even when I increase `max.print` to its maximum). I also don't think I can write to `.txt` file or `.csv` file because of the multiple objects and I get the error message:

```
Error in data.frame(description = "Global Model", dataname = "SCM.RData",  : 
 arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 10, 11, 20
```

I've also tried View, and indexing the `.Rdata` file to view components separately but no success. Is there another way to view the contents of an `.Rdata` file?

Comment: Are you open to printing each object individually?  Or are you looking for a wham-bam-thank you ma'am tool which can print an entire RData file?

Comment: Very open to printing each object individually. 
I was trying to achieve this using the indexing idea suggested in this post:  <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700619/get-specific-object-from-rdata-file> 
but couldn't get it to work- it just kept printing the list of objects.

Comment: try str() on your objects to see their structure.