# How to load a single object from .Rdata file?

Tags: r

I have a big .Rdata file that when I tried to load workspace. I got error.

`Error: cannot allocate vector of size n Gb`

I only want to get a dataframe from .Rdata file. How can I load a single object from .Rdata file?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb

Comment: @RonakShah - i'm not sure that question addresses the specific issue here. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700619/get-specific-object-from-rdata-file might be more useful

Comment: IF you only want to load a single dataframe, consider using the function shown here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65964065/4882696