# R - load a single data set from a RDA file that has multiple objects

Tags: r

I have some files saved from a different computer using `save()` whereby several objects were stored in RDA file.

However, the new computer doesn't have space for all the files so I want to just load my main file. How can I load only that file from the session?

```
library(dplyr)

iris <- iris
cars <- cars

save(list = c("iris", "cars"), file = "myData.Rdata")
```

Attempt to load:

```
load(file="myData.Rdata", object = "cars")
```

I have tried using the lazyLoad() DB method suggested but get an error about the file is still too big to load at the creation of the db.

Comment: Generates an error - DB is too big to load, 14.5GB.

Comment: [There's a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700619/get-specific-object-from-rdata-file) but it seems the issue is insufficient memory in your new computer. Perhaps there is a way to manipulate RData files on disk, but I don't know it.

Comment: If you have access to the old system, load the file there and then save the data sets to separate files. I do not see that `load` has any argument called `object=` (`args(load)`).

Comment: @dcarlson thanks, unfortunately not an option. I'm not aware of an object argument but it's sort of what I'd expect, I'm surprised it's so difficult for something so simple....