# R seed-sedding not "setting", results not reproducing

Tags: r, random, parallel-processing

I've got a script that looks like this:

```
#This is the master script.  It runs all other scripts.
rm(list=ls()) 

#Run data cleaing script
source("datacleaning.R")

set.seed(413) #Seed pre-selected as lead author's wife's birthday (April 13th)
reps=128

#Make imputated datasets
source("makeimps.R")

#Model selection step 1.  
source("model_selection.1.R")
load("AIC_results.1")
AIC_results

#best model removed the year interaction

#Model selection step 2.  removed year interaction
source("model_selection.2.R")
load("AIC_results.2")
AIC_results

#all interactions pretty good.  keeping this model

#Final selected model:
source("selectedmodel.R")
```

I send this master script to a supercomputing cluster; it takes about 17 hours of CPU time and 40 minutes of walltime on 32 cores.  (Hence my non-reproducible example).  But when I run the script, look at the results, then run it again, and look at the results again, they are slightly different.  Why?  I set the seed!  Does the seed get reset somehow?  Do I need to specify the seed inside of each script file?

I need to increase the number of reps, because its clear that I haven't converged sufficiently.  But that's a separate issue.  Why are my results here not reproducing themselves and how do I fix?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:  I'm doing the parallelization through `doMC` and `plyr`.  Some light googling based on comments below turns up the fact that one can't really set a "parallel seed" using these packages.  I'd need to migrate my code to `SNOW` somehow.  If anyone knows a solution with `doMC` and `plyr`, I'd be grateful to learn what it is.

Comment: Look in those RData files that you seem to be saving. In any of them, is there a `.Random.seed` object? Try using the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4831050/1465387).

Comment: If any of the files you are sourcing use the R multicore package, have a look at this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3534

Comment: @hrbrmstr: thats it.  got some digging to do.  thanks.

Comment: You want to (at least) read the vignette of the `parallel` package that has been part of Base R for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [`doRNG`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doRNG/vignettes/doRNG.pdf) package, specifically developed for this kind of reproducible parallel computing. Set the seed inside the call to the loop and you will be able to reproduce your results exactly...

```
require(doParallel)
require(doRNG)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)


unlist( foreach( i = 1:4 , .options.RNG = 413 ) %dorng% { runif(1) } )
#[1] 0.5251507 0.4326805 0.6409496 0.5523651

unlist( foreach( i = 1:4 , .options.RNG = 413 ) %dorng% { runif(1) } )
#[1] 0.5251507 0.4326805 0.6409496 0.5523651
```

Comment: But this approach won't work with `plyr`, will it?  Is there a way to ask `plyr` to use '%dorng%' rather than '%dopar%'?

Comment: OP here:  ^ my question exactly.

Comment: @SteveWeston @ACD I do not know `plyr` so well. It would beneficial if you could post some code that shows a trivial example of what you are doing with `plyr` to see if it could be ported to use `%dorng%` instead. One thought that occurs, is that instead of using `plyr` to split the jobs across cores, you split the job using `%dorng%` and then use `plyr` within each job to process the data on a single core? Can you partition your data before it is used by `plyr`?

Comment: These suggestions make a lot of sense to me. Many uses of `plyr` translate easily to `foreach`, and then `%dorng%` can be used as in this answer. It's not easy to guarantee reproducible results even in `snow`, which is one of the reasons for the old `snowFT` package.