# Is there a way to read the contents of an .RDS file without loading it all into memory?

Tags: r

I have a .RDS file that contains many lists, and that was created from a computer with more memory than the one from which I'm trying to read the same data.

Is there any way to access this content without loading it all into memory ?

Here is an example:

```
listOflists <- list(list1 = list(rnorm(1000)),
                    list2 = list(rnorm(1000)))
saveRDS(listOflists, "listOflists.RDS")
```

Is it possible to read list1 only, without loading the whole file ?

Comment: Similar, but disappointing: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4831050/946850

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700619/get-specific-object-from-rdata-file