# How to extract code from .Rdata file?

Tags: r, function, model, rdata

I have .Rdata file that "stores" some logic/code.
How can I extract the code written in this .Rdata file?

I want to edit/fix this code, but instead the general pipeline loads this .Rdata with it's variables and SVM model without the option to fix and edit.

Please advise.

P.S .Rdata saves a workspace, which includes the function and value objects created during an open session in R, I need the actual logic/code/initialization done in order to create these objects, for example I get the svm model fit result but not the code that created this object, that is what I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [listing contents of an R data file without loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831050/listing-contents-of-an-r-data-file-without-loading)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nope, my question is asking for a way to recover the code created the objects saved in .Rdata.

Comment: I attempted an answer below.  Maybe your question is not an exact duplicate, though I think it is closely related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try loading the `RData` file, and listing its contents:

```
load("mydata.RData", verbose=TRUE)
```

Then, you can view the code behind the objects loaded.  For instance, if you just loaded a function called `myfunc` you could view the definition by just entering the function's name:

```
myfunc
```